# How to remove default axis from the plot produced by boxplot()?

Tags: r, boxplot

Probably this is a simple question,

Does anyone know how to hide the default axis x labels in `boxplot()` in R?

It should be simple, but I search on several sites and on boxplot help  but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
 d <- data.frame(x = 2, y=1:5) 
 boxplot(d)
 boxplot(d, axes=FALSE) # add axes=FALSE to remove axes
```

you can then add axes however you please:

e.g.

```
 d <- data.frame(x = 2, y=1:5) 
 boxplot(d, axes=FALSE)
 axis(2, at=1:5, labels=c(rep("whatever I want",5)))
```

---

EDIT as per your comment:

remove default labels:

```
 boxplot(d, xaxt="n")
```

Comment: Thanks user1317221_G, This is the right solution for my answer, but what I really wanted was to hide the default x axis labels...